# Radio button with form input in JSP using Struts framework

Tags: java, html, jsp, radio-button, struts-1

I am trying to create a page to initialize what geolocation API to use. This page will have two radio buttons to switch between choices. I have created  two radio buttons as so:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
       <bean:message key="config.geolocation.page.text"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="odd" width="20%" nowrap>
       <bean:message key="editvarref.header.geolocation.pick.api"/>
    </td>
    <td class="odd" width="80%">
       <div>
         <html:radio styleId="logo_type_0" property="b_type" value="0" onclick="show_logo(false)" />
        <label for="b_type_0"><bean:message key="geolocation.use.google"/></label>
       </div>
       <div style="padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px;">
          <html:radio styleId="b_type_1" property="b_type" value="1" onclick="show_logo(true)" />
          <label for="bo_type_1"><bean:message key="geolocation.use.skyhook"/></label>
       </div>
     </td>
</tr>
```

How can I modify the radio buttons to show different input fields where the user can input values. I am trying to make both radio button show different input fields. So when one is chosen it will show certain fields and when the other is clicked it will show different fields. The fields will be a text box where users can input information

Comment: You can read Google Developer Guide.

Comment: @RomanC the question is not regarding the API, its regarding radio buttons and input fields

Comment: Write some JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

**SCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".text").hide()

});
function getResults(elem) {
elem.checked && elem.value == "Show" ? $(".text").show() : $(".text").hide();
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" name="radio1" value="Show" onClick="getResults(this)">
Do nothing                                                         
<input type="radio" name="radio1" value="Nothing" onclick="getResults(this)">
```